# Changing the default decoder aac(native) into aac(libfdk_aac) or aac(libfaac)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mp3, aac

Is is posible to change default decorder of ffmpeg?
If I use

```
ffmpeg -i pipe_video.fifo -i pipe_audio.fifo -c:v copy -f flv file.flv
```

ffmpeg automatically changes aac(native) into (mp3)libmp3lame (!!!!). I just wanna copy the stream automatically. No more. input pipe_audio.fifo is adts (libfaac)

Comment: Why not `-c:a copy`? Or `-c copy`?

Comment: Due to synchonization reason: http://superuser.com/questions/865088/ffmpeg-synchonization-of-libfdk-aac-or-libfacc-and-libx264

Comment: Please only ask one question about a problem.

Comment: I need simple copying video and audio streams. If I use decoder/encoder of aac audio stream the streams out of sync. How to achive this correct streaming?