# ffmpeg synchonization of libfdk_aac (or libfacc) and libx264

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, aac

How to synchronize libfdk_aac and libx264 streams?

```
ffmpeg -i pipe_libfdk_aac.fifo -i pipe_libx264.fifo -c copy -f flv flv_stream_pipe_or_rtmp.output
```

I'm always receiving the same asych in all cases: saving file on file system, rtmp-using or raw pipe out.
Is it possible to syncronize them?

```
 ffmpeg version N-66924-gaba61b2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jan 15 2015 12:50:29 with gcc 4.6 (GCC) 20120106 (prerelease)
configuration: --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --target-os=linux --enable-runtime-cpudetect --prefix=/data/data/info.guardianproject.ffmpeg/app_opt --enable-pic --disable-shared --enable-static --cross-prefix=/home/qwerty/work/android-ndk-r10b86/android-ndk-r10b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/home/qwerty/work/android-ndk-r10b86/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-3/arch-arm --extra-cflags='-I/home/qwerty/x264 -I/home/qwerty/ffmpeg_build/mp3/build/include -I/home/qwerty/faac/output/include -I/home/qwerty/ffmpeg_sources/fdk-aac/build/include -I/usr/local/include/ -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/qwerty/x264 -L/home/qwerty/ffmpeg_build/mp3/build/lib -L/home/qwerty/ffmpeg_sources/fdk-aac/build/lib -L/home/qwerty/faac/output/lib -L/usr/local/lib/ -lrtmp -lpolarssl' --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --disable-doc --enable-yasm --enable-decoders --enable-encoders --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-filters --enable-avresample --enable-librtmp --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --disable-indevs --enable-indev=lavfi --disable-outdevs --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-libx264 --enable-zlib --enable-muxer=md5
libavutil      54. 10.100 / 54. 10.100
libavcodec     56.  8.100 / 56.  8.100
libavformat    56.  9.100 / 56.  9.100
libavdevice    56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
libavfilter     5.  1.106 /  5.  1.106
libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

Comment: Please include the full uncut command line output.

Comment: flv_stream_pipe_or_rtmp.output is '-' or 'file.flv'

Comment: No, I mean, what `ffmpeg` outputs as log information. Starting with `ffmpeg version x.x.x, Copyright...`

Comment: @slhck updated the post

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the full, complete, and uncut output from your command.

Comment: It was uncut command. "ffmpeg -i pipe_libfdk_aac.fifo -i pipe_libx264.fifo -c copy -f flv file.flv" But I've tested the other parts of my code. I found some bugs which gave me wrong fps from camera raw data. Anyway thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

## Causes of desynchronization between video and audio

### 1. The framerate of the video

The cause of audio/video desynchronization is always framerate. Nothing else. The solution is to choose a different framerate and try again. Here's how to do this with `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 60 output.mp4
```

For maximum compatibility of your video with obscure players (looking at you, TikTok) it's better to be explicit in specifying the video codec, the framerate, the audio codec, and even the pixel format (use YUV420p):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -filter:v format=yuv420p -r 60 output.mp4
```

I found all of this out the hard way so trust me, this is a battle-tested way to encode videos that play everywhere.

Comment: Answer in seven years. Stack overflow is really great